# How can I replace this string inside a file using bash?

Tags: regex, bash

Would like to write a bash script that replaces some strings in a text file, however I am getting hung up on how to replace the contents inside a 'value' for a variable.

Suppose the value I wish to set inside a text file could be :

`TCP_IN = "123,35,995"`

.. where `123,35,995` could be any string (not just numbers with commas.

How could I replace this keypair searching for `TCP_IN = "*"` and set the value inside where `*` is, from within a bash script ?

Comment: Check [this demo](http://ideone.com/PqnKMz)

Comment: Awesome :)   .. Thank you very much !!!!!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why not an answer here?

Comment: Posted and explained a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -E 's/(TCP_IN *= *")[^"]+/\1MyNewVal/g'
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/PqnKMz)

The regex matches and captures into Group 1 `TCP_IN` followed with zero or more spaces, followed with a `=` symbol, followed with again zero or more spaces, and then `[^"]+` matches 1 or more characters other than a `"` (`[^...]` is a *negated character class that matches all characters but those defined inside the char class).

Comment: Just a quick note on this, to use a variable named `MyNewVal`, you can do it as follows : `sed -E 's/(TCP_IN *= *")[^"]+/\1'$MyNewVal'/g'`

Comment: i have a small issue with running multiple of these consecutively.  http://ideone.com/xUuhMq  results in zeroing the file size.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, none of the variables have `'` in them ? The syntax works > http://ideone.com/0j1VDt  . Only once, not when run consecutively.  :)

Comment: Sorry, missed the first comment. Just a sec.

Comment: No problem, I posted this as a question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876027/multiple-sed-in-bash-script-results-in-file-being-zero-bytes